# How to write a custom control, which can auto resize just like TextBox in a grid cell?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have tried to override MeasureOverride, but the available size will not change when i resize a grid. which contains my control.

```
class MyFrameworkElement : FrameworkElement 
{
    override Size MeasureOverride(Size available)
    {
        this.Width = available.Width;
        this.Height = available.Width
        this.UpdateLayout();  // do something...
    }
}
```

This works only when application start.

How to implement a auto resize control, just like a TextBox in a grid cell. The TextBox will auto resize to fill grid cell if grid resized.

Comment: Please specify your visual tree of 'MyFrameworkElement'? With out that it is hard to explain. Because most of the controls in WPF are 'free sized' means whatever size its parent gave, it utilizes that except when we set Height/Width

Answer (score 1):

It should resize it automatically, if you [anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384314.aspx) your control to the form (something the user of your control does, not the control itself).